# issue with warpPerspective() with any rotation matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use warpPerspective() by manually defining a matrix and passing it.
I calculated a rotation matrix on this website: https://www.energid.com/resources/orientation-calculator.
The result is just a black image eventhough it should only rotate by 0.1 radians around the x-axis.
Here is my code

```
Mat warpMat = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.9950042, -0.0998334, 0.0000000, 0.0998334, 0.9950042;
cv::Size size(3216, 2136);
warpPerspective(src, dst, warpMat, size);
imwrite("warp.png", dst);
```

I tried:

- a bunch of different angles
- another website to calculate the matrix
- rearranging the numbers of the matrix in case columns are superior to rows (from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to 1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9)

but nothing worked. Sometimes the image is just black and sometimes there are white lines. But never any version of my initial image except for (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) of cause.

Answer (score -1):

The link you reference (https://www.energid.com/resources/orientation-calculator) is not the right math for `cv::warpPerspective` -- it is for a 3D rotation matrix.  Warp perspective is a 2D affine transformation (or homogeneous coordinate transformation), so you need a rotation matrix that looks like this:

```
[ cos(t) -sin(t) xoff 
  sin(t) cos(t)  yoff
     0     0       1 ]
```

Where `xoff` and `yoff` are x and y translations of the source image.  You can look here for more info (http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node108.html).

So try this instead:

```
Mat warpMat = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0.9950042, -0.0998334, 0.0, 0.0998334, 0.9950042, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0000000, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I think I need to do a perspective transformation instead of a 2D affine transformation. I want to rectify an image by changing the camera pose which is given by the three angles. There is another function warpAffine() which takes a 2x3 matrix. warpPerspective() on the other hand takes a 3x3 matrix and "applies a perspective transformation" according to opencv. To my understanding a perspective transformation goes beyond what affine transformation can do, right?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your goal, but rectification would be removing distortion from the image due to the lens, whereas changing the pose of the camera would be akin to warpPerspective and homographic transformations.  The three angles, I'm assuming are Euler anlges (pitch/roll/yaw)?

Comment: Yes, I have to undistort the image before aswell, but that is not rectification (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification). Yes, that's right, it's Euler angles. Do you have an idea how to I could use the Euler angles for warpPerspective?

Comment: I believe what you need to do is calculate the 3D rotation matrix using the Euler angles -- should be able to use the orientation calculator above for that.  Then apply that transformation matrix to some reference points (whatever points you want, start with image corners) in the source image coordinate system and call `cv::findHomography` on the source and transformed points to get the projective or perspective transformation matrix, to view it as if it were viewed from the new camera pose.  There is probably a slick way of doing this in one step, but I can't find one.

Comment: That should work, thank you! I might be wrong but maybe stereoRectify() could provide me the matrix that I need (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6).
It takes a rotation matrix as input and outputs a 3x3 rectification transform for one camera to the other and vice versa. I'll try it tomorrow.